# Retrieving Single Records when using a union and 2 tables

Tags: mysql, union

I am using the following sql to get the total jobs in each month from 2 tables. The import table are live jobs that have yet to be completed and the import_archive table holds completed jobs.

I need to count all of the jobs in each week from the two tables and display them.

I am using the following SQL which works but shows duplicate week records where jobs are in both tables. I need these to be added together to show 1 record rather than 2 for the same week.

```
(SELECT
    WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date) AS weekno, 
    COUNT(1) AS Jobs,
    SUBDATE(Job_Start_Date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(Job_Start_Date) DAY) AS Week_Start_Date
FROM import where Job_Work_Type='PPD'
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date))
union

(SELECT
    WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date) AS weekno, 
    COUNT(1) AS Jobs,
    SUBDATE(Job_Start_Date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(Job_Start_Date) DAY) AS Week_Start_Date
FROM import_archive where Job_Work_Type='PPD'
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date))
```

Why do I need to change to show just a single record for each week even though 2 tables are being used?

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean. If you show us what you're currently getting with that query and then what you'd like to get, we can assist.

Comment: Do the union first then the weekof year, count and sub of dates...

Answer (score 0):

You need to `UNION ALL` the two tables start_dates first then get your counts  and date parsing.  UNION All because we want to keep duplicate dates as they could be for different jobs.  If you need more data/columns be sure to union ALL both sets before doing the analysis/manipulation.

Simply put: generate a master set of data containing all data from both tables, then do the counts/data manipulation.

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date) AS weekno
     , COUNT(1) AS Jobs
     , SUBDATE(Job_Start_Date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(Job_Start_Date) DAY) AS Week_Start_Date
FROM (SELECT Job_Start_date
      FROM import where Job_Work_Type='PPD'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Job_Start_date
      FROM import_archive where Job_Work_Type='PPD')
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date
```

Or you have to aggregate again after you generate two distinct data sets.

```
SELECT weekno, sum(jobs) as jobs, week_start_Date
FROM (
(SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date) AS weekno
      , COUNT(1) AS Jobs
      , SUBDATE(Job_Start_Date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(Job_Start_Date) DAY) AS Week_Start_Date
FROM import where Job_Work_Type='PPD'
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date)
)
union

(SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date) AS weekno
      , COUNT(1) AS Jobs
      , SUBDATE(Job_Start_Date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(Job_Start_Date) DAY) AS Week_Start_Date
 FROM import_archive where Job_Work_Type='PPD'
 GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(Job_Start_Date)
)
)
GROUP BY weekNo, weekStart_date
```

Comment: When I run either of your suggestions I get the following error message.

Every derived table must have its own alias

What do I need to change in the SQL?

Alan